# Can hangouts send text-only MMS to certain contacts?

Tags: sms, mms, google-hangouts

Most of my friends and family have iPhones that are capable of receiving MMS messages. I'd like to be able to type longer messages without having them be broken up into smaller SMS messages, because they often arrive out of order when going to a different carrier.

Is there a way to force Hangouts to send MMS messages when the text is too long for one message? Even better would be if I could have certain contacts set to always receive MMS no matter what.

Answer (score 0):

To convert a long SMS into a MMS, Long press the attachment paperclip to add a subject line in the hangouts app